# How to change color of font icons in android

Tags: android, icon-fonts

I am making one chat application in this i am using icon fonts with reference [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/),I have saved ttf file into my project assets folder after that i am accessing icons using by setting typeface,problem is i want to change size,color of icon font.Please help me

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/landing_drawer_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_40"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_40"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_black_1000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Drawable"
        />

viewHolder.drawerItemImage.setText("A");
```

Comment: Post your xml please

Comment: What happens when you do this: icon.setTextColor(Color RED);

Comment: try rendering html data and apply local css to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this :

Set a color in your colors.xml :

```
<color name="test">#0f0f0f</color>
```

In your XML do this :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/landing_drawer_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_40"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_40"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:textColor="@color/test"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Drawable"
        />
```

To set the `TypeFace` you can do it by two ways

1.-

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(
getContext().getAssets(), 
"fonts/YourTypeFace.ttf");
YourTextView.setTypeface(font);
```

2.- `android:typeface="YOURTTF"`

To set your `TextSize` you have to add in your xml file

```
 android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"/>
```

Try this and if you have any problem let me know, hope my answered helped you somehow :)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");

    gmail_icon.setTypeface(font);

    gmail_icon.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```